# Recursive call error with stored function

Tags: oracle

I created this stored function :

```
create or replace function recuperer_ascendants_structure(p_struct_code varchar2, previous_codes varchar2)
return varchar2
is
    sep varchar2(1) := '';
    ret varchar2(4000);
    v_ascendant_code structure.str_struct_code%type;
begin
    execute immediate 'select str_struct_code from structure where struct_code = :1' into v_ascendant_code using p_struct_code;
    if v_ascendant_code is null then
        if previous_codes is null then
            return p_struct_code;
        else
            return p_struct_code || ',' || previous_codes;
        end if;
    else
        if previous_codes is null then
            ret := recuperer_ascendants_structure(v_ascendant_code , v_ascendant_code);
        else
            ret := recuperer_ascendants_structure(v_ascendant_code , p_struct_code || ',' || v_ascendant_code);
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

At runtime I get this error :

```
SQL> select recuperer_ascendants_structure('21.12.07',null) prts from dual;
select recuperer_ascendants_structure('21.12.07',null) prts from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value
ORA-06512: at "SSE.RECUPERER_ASCENDANTS_STRUCTURE", line 22
ORA-06512: at "SSE.RECUPERER_ASCENDANTS_STRUCTURE", line 17
```

So what is wrong ?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need dynamic SQL here, you can simply use: `select str_struct_code  into v_ascendant_code from structure where struct_code = p_struct_code`

Comment: Nice to see neatly laid out PL/SQL by the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to avoid multiple RETURN statements. Collect information about the final result (RET variable in your code) anywhere, but return it only once, at the end of the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recuperer_ascendants_structure (
   p_struct_code     VARCHAR2,
   previous_codes    VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   sep                VARCHAR2 (1) := '';
   ret                VARCHAR2 (4000);
   v_ascendant_code   structure.str_struct_code%TYPE;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'select str_struct_code from structure where struct_code = :1'
      INTO v_ascendant_code
      USING p_struct_code;

   IF v_ascendant_code IS NULL
   THEN
      IF previous_codes IS NULL
      THEN
         ret := p_struct_code;
      ELSE
         ret := p_struct_code || ',' || previous_codes;
      END IF;
   ELSE
      IF previous_codes IS NULL
      THEN
         ret :=
            recuperer_ascendants_structure (v_ascendant_code,
                                            v_ascendant_code);
      ELSE
         ret :=
            recuperer_ascendants_structure (
               v_ascendant_code,
               p_struct_code || ',' || v_ascendant_code);
      END IF;
   END IF;

   RETURN ret;  --> here!
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

This error reason can be read as is: 'Function returned without value'. Is means that execution reachs the final `end` without any `return` statement so there is no any value which can be returned to caller.

It looks like you should replace `ret :=` with `return` to avoid this error.